# How to \renewcommand with 2 arguments?

Tags: macros

I have got a specific problem in LaTeX: when I type `\sqrt[3]{x}`, the compilator should interpret it as `\sqrt[\text{\scriptsize{3}}]{x}`, so that the digit is the same size as powers. The general question is how to renew a command with two arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your general request on "how to renew a command with two arguments" depends on how these arguments are defined. In your case, `\sqrt` takes two arguments, the first of which is optional. In such cases, care may be required to correctly copy the definition of original command. See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764). In the case of `\sqrt`, you can use

```
\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[2][]{\oldsqrt[\text{\scriptsize{#1}}]{#2}}
```

However, if the original `\sqrt` was defined using `\newcommand` (and not a `\def` with `\@ifnextchar` conditional), then you would need

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldsqrt\sqrt
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[2][]{\oldsqrt[\text{\scriptsize{#1}}]{#2}}
```

Without an optional argument, the redefinition would be a simple copy-and-renewcommand:

```
\let\oldmacro\macro
\renewcommand{\macro}[2]{%
  \oldmacro{#2}{#1}}% New handling of arguments in reverse order, say
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not recommendable to redefine `\sqrt`. Instead, define a new command, say `\ssqrt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%If you do actually want to redefine \sqrt, then uncomment the following lines
%\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
%\renewcommand{\sqrt}[2][]{\oldsqrt[\text{\scriptsize{#1}}]{#2}}
\newcommand{\ssqrt}[2][]{\sqrt[\text{\scriptsize{#1}}]{#2}}
\begin{document}
$\ssqrt[text]{x^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first variant is not working, my computer just heats up even in the empty file with only your code.

Comment: See again. It's corrected now.